# MP4 video not playing on Apache 2 server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, html5-video

I've hosted a static website on Apache2 server on AWS EC2 instance. I have a video which is not playing when it is hosted there on any browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari). Video is working fine when tested locally. I've added following to the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf inside `<IfModule mime_module>`.

```
`AddType video/mp4 .mp4`
```

I also tried adding above to .htaccess file in the root directory of my website (/var/www/html as well as /var/www/). Any pointers that can help here?

Comment: restarted the server?

Comment: Yes I did. I got the issue though. I'd provided wrong path of video (basically issue). The point is, it was running locally without any issues. Any pointers why it might be running locally?